How to find the volume and surface area of a curved Prismatoid
I am trying to find the volume and surface area of what is essentially a truncated pyramidal frustum, like a prism where all 4 sides are Trapezoidal. However, the corners do not converge at points, but rather in a constant radius. (The two bases are rectangles with rounded corners of the same size, instead of sharp corners. See images below.)
I have found the formula for the volume of a pyramidal frustum as
$$
V=\frac{1}{3}h(A_1+A_2+\sqrt{A_1A_2})
$$
Where $h$ is the height, and $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the area of the Top and Bottom bases respectively. Will this formula work? All examples of its use that I have seen are of shapes with only sharp corners.
For the Surface area I found a similar formula for frustums
$$
S=\frac{1}{2}(p_1+p_2)s
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the perimeters of the Top and Bottom bases, and $s$ is the slant height. Again, will this work, and if so how would I find the value of $s$?
This is also an idealized version of the shape I am trying to measure. There are irregularities that I will have to include, such as one of the sides is not perfectly straight. However as long as I can get a close estimate I think I should be able to assume the error.
Images:
Dimensions of the object (418'x532' bottom base, 184'x298' top base. Height is 39', Corner radius is 50')

A 3D render of the object. Assume the corners are smooth, not jagged as shown.  
Edit: I found this post that seems to agree that the Volume formula can be used with any irregular shape, but I still do not know about the Surface area.
Edit 2: Added inline photos and descriptions

If possible, please include a picture/diagram of this.

The formulas that start with $h/3$ times area volumes (including the frustrum formulas that subract these) are only valid if the areas scale quadratically with the distance from the base, which means if the linear scales of the edges scale linearly with the height
above the base. If your round edges are for example parts of slanted cylinders with constant radius, the formulas are wrong. One cannot give precise answers to your questions because you did not define the particular cross sections of these rounded edges.

@R.J.Mathar to clarify, because the corners are cylindrical and don't change radius as the height goes up, the formula will not work? Also, I added an additional photo. Which cross section are you referring to?

The cross sections are the horizontal cross sections at constant altitude above the base, the projection on the x-y plane that the engineers draw. If the corners were, for example, cut from a circular pyramid, the formula would be valid, but not in your case. If the corners are pieces of circles such that one can write down the area of the cross section (4 sides plus circular segments plus rounded lid) in analytical form, it's still possible to obtain analytical expressions for the volume by just integrating along the z-axis...

By the symmetry of a symmetry z-axis of order 2, the volume is 4 times the volume integrated in the region $0\le x\le A$, $0\le y \le B$, $A=532/2=266$, $B=418/2=209$.
$x$ in the image is to the right, $y$ up. $z$ is from the base to the top, $0\le z\le 39=h$.
At the top, the cross section is inside $0\le x\le a=298/2=149$, $0\le y\le b=184/2=92$.
[The difference $A-a=117 = B-b$ in relation to $h=39$ is the 1:3 slope compatible with the image.]
The $a\times b$ bounding box of the cross section (including the small piece outside the quarter-circle) at altitude $z$ is
linearly shrinking with z:
$$
a(z) = A-\frac{A-a}{h}z, b(z) = B-\frac{B-b}{h}z.
$$
At a general altitude $z$, the cross sectional area $F$ can be split into three non-overlapping simpler
areas: (i) a quarter circle of radius $R=50$ (ii) a rectangle $[a(z)-R] \times b(z)$ to the left of the quarter-circle,
(iii) a rectangle $R\times [b(z)-R]$ below the quarter-circle. The sum of these areas, the cross section
at altitude $z$, is
$$
F(z)=\frac{\pi}{4}R^2 + [a(z)-R]b(z)+R[b(z)-R]
$$
$$
=\frac{AB-aB+ab-Ab}{h^2}z^2+\frac{Ab+aB-2AB}{h}z+\frac{\pi R^2}{4}+AB-R^2.
$$
Note that $F(0)=55057.49541 = 220229.9816/4$ and $F(39)=13171.49541=52685.98164/4$ compatible with the image.
The volume in the region $x,y\ge 0$ is
$$
\int_0^h F(z)dz = (3\pi R^2+4AB-12R^2+2Ab+2aB+4ab)\frac{h}{12},
$$
and the total volume of the body with the factor 4 (due to the symmetry mentioned above) is
$$
V = (3\pi R^2+4AB-12R^2+2Ab+2aB+4ab)\frac{h}{3} \approx 4.965947\times 10^6.
$$
[The wrong formula gives $h(F(0)+F(h)+\sqrt{F(0)F(h)})/3\approx 4.94823\times 10^6$.]
The surface of the body is the base surface $4F(0)$ plus the top surface $4F(h)$ --- factors 4 from the
symmetry splitting --- plus 2 times the surface of the isoceless larger slanted trapezoidal side face plus 2 times the
surface of the smaller slanted isoceless trapezoidal side face plus 4 times the surface of a single chopped cylinder.
The larger trapezoidal side face has horizontal parallel side lengths $2A-2R$ at $y=B,z=0$ and $2a-2R$ at $y=b,z=h$
(factors 2 as we have defined $A,a,B,b$ lengths in only one quadrant).
The shortest spatial distance between
these sides
can be calculated from the Euclidean distance of a line starting at $(x,y,z)=(0,B,0)$ at the base and ending at $(0,b,h)$
at the top, which is $\sqrt{(B-b)^2+h^2}$. The area of the trapezoid is the arithmetic average
of the parallel sides multiplied by shortest distance, $[(2A-2R)+(2a-2R)]\sqrt{(B-b)^2+h^2}/2$.
Swapping the role
$a\leftrightarrow b, A\leftrightarrow B$
gives the area of each of the two the smaller trapezoids, $[(2B-2R)+(2b-2R)]\sqrt{(A-a)^2+h^2}/2$.
The area of a single visible cylinder surface is a quarter of the perimeter, $\pi R/2$, times
the path length sliding from base to top, which is the same as the side length of the trapezoids.
That common 3rd side length of the trapezoids is the distance between point $(x,y,z)=(A-R,B,0)$ at the base and
$(x,y,z) = (a-R,b,h)$ at the top, $\sqrt{(A-a)^2+(B-b)^2+h^2}$.
$$
S = 4F(0)+4F(h)
$$
$$
+2[2A+2a-4R]\sqrt{(B-b)^2+h^2}/2
$$
$$
+2[2B+2b-4R]\sqrt{(A-a)^2+h^2}/2
$$
$$
+4 \frac{\pi R}{2} \sqrt{(A-a)^2+(B-b)^2+h^2}
\approx 453597.46
$$

Thank you for this, this is definitely the correct answer. However, I believe there might be an error in your Surface area calculation. You use [$A+a-2R$], but should it not be [$2A+2a-4R$] since your $A$ and $a$ are only half of the actual length of the full trapezoid? Each trapezoid has a top length of 298-100 and a bottom length of 532-100, for the average length of 315, whereas yours gives the average length of 157.5 (half of what I found)

Yes, this seems to be an error. I'll edit my solution to cover this up....
